# find related specific word from first sentence

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Example :

I have this string in a file (**number $1one bla bla $2second**)
First, I use regex to find this line

> number $1one bla bla $2second

And then after that line was found, I need to match the word that contains '$' in another line
Example :

number **$1one** bla bla **$2second**

=> **$1one**

=> **$2second**

Another line:

> this is bla bla bla **$2second** bla bla
>
> bla bla **$2second** in bla bla
>
> another bla bla **$1one** bla **$3third** bla **$2second**
>
> **$1one** bla bla bla

After above line was found, find another word that contains '$' again (example above : **$3third**)

> another bla bla bla **$3third** bla **$2second**
>
> **$3third** bla bla bla

**until all '$' word already found (no more new word contains '$')**

I already get the first step using regex, The problem is I don't know how to search another specific word after using regex. should I used regex once again or is there another method to find this?

Comment: what do mean with *another specific word*? are you searching the exact words? If not, what is your pattern?

Comment: more like the exact pattern using regex (\$[\w-]*). so every word with '$' in it will match in another line.

Comment: `[x for line in file for x in re.findall('\$\w+\b',line)]` will give you all `$words` in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED after clarification on OP**

```
#import regex the new regex library that helps with \K flag
import regex as re

s="""this is bla bla bla $2second bla bla
And then after that line was found, I need to match the word that contains '$' in another line Example :
number $1one bla bla $2second
And then after that line was found, I need to match the word that contains '$' in another line Example :
number $1one bla bla $2second
=> $1one
=> $2second
Another line:
this is bla bla bla $2second bla bla
bla bla $2second in bla bla
another bla bla bla $5fifth bla $4fourth
another bla bla $1one bla $3third bla $2second
$1one bla bla bla
After above line was found, find another word that contains '$' again (example above : $3third)
$4fourth bla bla bla'"""


def findre(s,valids=set([])):
    p=re.compile(r'(?=' + '|'.join(valids) + r').*?\K\$\w+\b|\$\w+\b(?=.*?(?:' + '|'.join(valids) + '))')
    l=p.findall(s)
    for x in l:
        valids.add(re.escape(x))
    return l

ss=s.split('\n')
dw=[x for s in ss for x in findre(s)]
print(dw)
```

---

**output**

```
['$2second', '$1one', '$2second', '$1one', '$2second', '$1one', '$2second', '$2second', '$2second', '$1one', '$3third', '$2second', '$1one', '$3third']
```

Note that it skipped dollar words `$4fourth` and `$5fifth` that do not have support from earlier tokens(dollar words).
One more thing I assumed here is that first support token is the first `$word` that we match from the beginning. If that is not the case then all you need to do is change

```
def findre(s,valids=set([])):
```

to

```
def findre(s,valids=set([$myfirsttoken,$mysecondtoken])):
```

This will make sure that the matches start from first match of these tokens/`$words`

Also I just used `\w` you could replace it with `[\w-]`

---

**Explanation**

```
                    #START WITH A VALID
(?=                 #START Positive Lookahead forces start with one of following words, but does not include in match         
'|'.join(valids)    #Creates a string of $1one|$2two and builds as it picks up valids
)                   #End positive lookahead
.*?\K               #Any characters and \K drops them all, you can put this inside positive lookahead if you want
\$\w+\b             #Any $word after the conditions of starting with key word before this
|                   #OR if $validword comes after any $word
\$\w+\b             #Any $word that match condition that follows
(?=                 #Positive Lookahead forces the match to end with
.*?                 #Any characters
(?:                 #non capturing group->don't include in match
'|'.join(valids)    #Creates a string of $1one|$2two and builds as it picks up valids
)                   #End non capturing group
)                   #End positive lookahead
```

In regex "|" implies `OR` so `a|b|c` means match either `a` or `b` or `c`.

---

**UPDATE**
Using List option in the new regex library... The below makes it much simpler to use.

```
def addToValid(m):
    valids.add(m)
    return m

valids=set([])
dw=[addToValid(x) for s in ss for x in re.findall(r'(?=\L<l>.*?)\$\w+\b|\$\w+\b(?=.*?\L<l>)',s,l=valids)]
print(dw)
```

Comment: it works well, but I'm Sorry, I realized I didn't explain it clear enough. I mean with **"until all '$' word already found"** it's mean only the '$' word that already found in last sentence

I draw the example :
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl71D.jpg

Comment: Okay, so you want $words that occur more than once. And you want to discard $words that appear only once?

Comment: Alternatively you have a fixed set of $words that you want to match thus discarding all else?

Comment: it shouldn't have to be only one, I mean If $four appear twice , it doesn't include either because last sentence "another $2second found, new $3third found" doesn't have $four in it. so $four doesn't count.

Comment: Ah, so `another` and `new` are the key words?

Comment: actually another and new are examples. this "another" and "new" can be another word (ex: once upon a time, at the moment, etc.). so the real key word is the "$" word that already found. (in this case, the "$1one", "$2second" and "$3third").

Comment: Okay, so a $word comes into play only if it appears along with an already existing $word in the same sentence?

Comment: Like if $4four came in another same line with $1, then $4four is required as well?

Comment: I meant line instead of sentence.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charm! :) if you don't mind, can you explain "r'(?=' + '|'.join(valids)" and (?:' + '|'.join(valids) ? I'm a bit new to regex and understand basic regex but, the "|" sign between + and .join(valids) a bit confusing to me, is "|" sign equals to "or"? if it is, what's "|" try to compare in there?

Comment: have put some explanation of the regex for your benefit. I would also suggest you put statements like `print(p.pattern)` and `print(valids)` in the function `findre` to understand the flow of how things are working.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and explanation :) it helps me a lot

Comment: @maxi note a simplified version of the solution.